# ImageView layout on custom ViewGroup only moves "bounding box", not image

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, android-custom-view

I am trying to position an ImageView within a custom ViewGroup. Using the Graphical Layout in Eclipse, I can see that the bounding box is placed where I want, but the image itself stays at (0,0) of the parent.

Am I missing a measure- or layout-related call for the ImageView, or doing the layout positioning wrong? How can the image be separated from its layout boundaries?

Here's a screenshot of what I'm describing: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13477196/gameboard.png

And the code bits from the ViewGroup:

```
public class GameViewGroup extends ViewGroup {
...
    @Override
    public void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        for (int col = 0; col < COLS; ++col) {
            for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; ++row) {
                ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(pieceId[col][row]);
                final Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

                final int imgLeft = l + (int) board.getVertexX(col) - (bitmap.getWidth() / 2);
                final int imgTop = t + (int) board.getVertexY(col, row) - (bitmap.getHeight() / 2);
                final int imgRight = imgLeft + bitmap.getWidth();
                final int imgBot = imgTop + bitmap.getHeight();

                image.layout(imgLeft, imgTop, imgRight, imgBot);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // Draw the game board from cache
        canvas.drawBitmap(cachedBitmap, 0, 0, null);

        // Draw the pieces
        for (int col = 0; col < COLS; ++col) {
            for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; ++row) {
                ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(pieceId[col][row]);
                image.draw(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
...
}
```

I use XML to attach the ImageViews to the custom ViewGroup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GameViewGroup 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/game_view"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    tools:context=".GameActivity">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/piece1"
        android:src="@drawable/piece"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:contentDescription="@string/piece" />
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following under the call to image.layout() in onLayout():

```
image.setPadding(imgLeft, imgTop, imgRight, imgBot);
```

And that positioned the image in exactly the same place as the bounding box in the Eclipse Graphical Layout.

However, when launching the app on my device, it still doesn't work.